# Comportamento estranho na fila de análise - Respostas Tardias

Tags: suporte

Há alguma explicação para que um usuário tenha conseguido, à data, analisar 33 posts nesta semana e 169 neste mês, quando eu não consegui nenhuma?

Tenham em conta que eu verifico a fila com frequência.

Comment: Tendo em vista que a semana começa no domingo e que o limite diario é 20, 33 é um numero aceitavel. Agora quanto a não aparecer para você, confesso que faz tempo que não vejo nada dessa fila, como tem muita gente com rep pra analisar, e poucos posts, ai é "quem chegar primeiro". Sem contar nos que ficam atrás da medalha da fila.

Comment: @Articuno, eu seu isso. O estranho é haver uma discrepância tão grande entre o nº de análises conseguidas por esse usuário e os outros. Note que são precisas mais de uma análise por post.

Comment: Fanatismo por medalhas :P

Comment: @bigown sim, deve ser, eu também quero ganhá-la. Só não percebo o porquê de, tendo havido neste mês pelo menos 169 posts analisados, eu não ter conseguido analisar nenhum.

Comment: O motivo é justamente este, a concorrência, quando tem alguém dando F5 o tempo todo não dá espaço para outras pessoas ganharem.

Comment: @bigown Não é necessário haver mais de uma análise por post para que saia da fila?

Comment: Eu acho que esta fila é uma só, ela é quase classificatória.

Comment: @bigown Se é assim, então está explicado. No entanto, se verificar o histórico, existem algumas que foram analisadas por dois usuários. Suponho que deve haver algum tipo de regra por detrás.

Comment: É provável que seja de acordo com a análise, ou quem fez.

Comment: Certamente eles estão correndo para analisar logo, o que pode ser até bom.